# Perl install module fail on WIN10

Tags: windows-10, perl, cpan

I was trying to install **Spreadsheet::WriteExcel** module via CPAN tool for Aactive Perl(5.28.1 version).

However , when I executed command "cpan install Spreadsheet::WriteExcel" , it showed some error and terminated the installation automatically.

The log is showing down below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1NMp.png)

```
CPAN: Module::Build loaded ok (v0.4224)
Configuring J/JT/JTBRAUN/Parse-RecDescent-1.967015.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Parse::RecDescent
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  JTBRAUN/Parse-RecDescent-1.967015.tar.gz
  C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for J/JT/JTBRAUN/Parse-RecDescent-1.967015.tar.gz
'dmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
  JTBRAUN/Parse-RecDescent-1.967015.tar.gz
  dmake -- NOT OK
  JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory C:\Perl64\cpan\build\Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40-1
  JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
Running make for J/JM/JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40.tar.gz
Warning: Prerequisite 'OLE::Storage_Lite => 0.19' for 'JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40.tar.gz' failed when processing 'JMCNAMARA/OLE-Storage_Lite-0.19.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Warning: Prerequisite 'Parse::RecDescent => 0' for 'JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40.tar.gz' failed when processing 'JTBRAUN/Parse-RecDescent-1.967015.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
'dmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
  JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40.tar.gz
  dmake -- NOT OK
```

According to logs , I also tried to install dmake module , but still not working

Does anyone know how to fix this problem so I can install module properly?

Comment: You are missing two dependencies, `OLE::Storage_Lite` and `Parse::RecDescent`. Says it right in the error message. You are also missing the command [`dmake`](https://www.openoffice.org/tools/dmake/dmake_4.11.html) needed to compile the module. And if the module needs dmake, it's probably going to need a compiler too. Read the documentation for the module you are trying to install to see which one.